# How to hide the divide by zero exception in php?

Tags: php

i tried this `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);`

but its not working and printing the error like this...

> Warning: Division by zero in
>   C:\wamp\www\adman\webpage1\elearning.php
>   on line 276

Comment: Is this some external product you are using? If it isn't, you should fix the error

Comment: Test that the value you're dividing by isn't zero __before__ doing the division

Comment: In some cases it might be desirable to let the result be set to PHP's `INF` (infinity) constant ... as long as you don't try to perform calculations on it afterwards that can't handle infinity .. so in those cases it might be helpful to suppress those warnings, and using `@` to suppress all warnings might not be desirable.

Answer (score 10):

This is the best way to handle it:

```
if ( $divisor == 0 )
{
     // don't divide by zero, handle special case
} else {
     $result = $number / $divisor;
}
```